# How do I check if my Android SD is encrypted?

Tags: security, external-sd, sd-card, disk-encryption

I can't remember if I encrypted it already or not. How do I verify that?

Under SETTINGS - SECURITY - ENCRYPTION, there is just "Encrypted phone", but nothing related to the SD card.

The SD is NOT formatted as Internal, and I do NOT want to use that mode (I don't wanna risk to be slowed down; and wanna be free to take out my SD card and still have my phone working).

Comment: Power off your device, eject the sd card, place it in an sd card USB reader and connect it to a pc, then you will see if it is encrypted or not.

Comment: I thought about that but I don't have a pc nor an adapter for the card atm. And wanted to have an Android solution; there is for sure a way to know it directly from the OS.